# Max cut problem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, random-variables

I've just looked at the standard proof using the probabilistic method stating that the max cut problem has a lower bound of $|E|/2$ for any graph $G=(V,E)$. More specifically if $X$ is the random variable representing the cut size given by a random assignment of vertices to one of two sets then $X \geq |E|/2$.

An exercise asks to slightly improve the lower bound by showing that the largest cut must be strictly larger than $|E|/2$. Would it suffice to show that we can easily construct a cut of size less than $|E|/2$ by simply selecting $V_{1}=V$ and $V_{2}=\emptyset$ and so there exists a cut of size $0<\mathbb{E}(X).$ Thus there must exist a cut $X>\mathbb{E}(X)$.

Comment: Makes sense to me.